# Watermark or Encoding Error?

Tags: netflix, piracy

I was watching a show on Netflix this evening and a strange image flashed on the screen like a subliminal message ... I scrubbed back a few seconds and found the frame in question.

[image: strange image]

This does not look like any encoding error I have ever seen before ... is this some type of anti-piracy protection?  If so what all information is encoded in it?

EDIT: Netflix The Iron Fist S01E08 around 29:33s in 25:55s left

Comment: Could you give us the name of the show, and your country, so we can see if it also occurs to us?

Comment: Please tell us your country too. I checked in Netflix France and I couldn't see this frame.Also my version of the show is in color and it seems yours is in black and white.

Comment: @SilverBebs country is US, and no my version is in color that frame is just kinda dark in comparison to the green stuff in the foreground

Comment: I also checked, nothing abnormal here from The Netherlands.

Comment: The macro blocks make me think that it's some sort of corruption of the stream that probably went away with the next keyframe.

Comment: @user1118321 that is what I thought ... but rebooting the computer clearing cache and reloading the episode ... the image is still there.